# Is this XAML code possible?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have a silverlight app that I'm trying to keep as MVVM as possible.  I'm trying to set the datacontext of the page from a static resource on the page (so that I can reference the static resource later in a datagrid).  But I'm having problems getting this to work.  Is the following code possible?

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <local:ProposalViewModel x:Key="viewModel" />
</navigation:Page.Resources>
<navigation:Page.DataContext>
    <!-- Binding to the viewmodel exposed from 'viewModel' -->
</navigation:Page.DataContext>
```

Is there some statement that I can use to put into the Page.DataContext binding so that it points at the same instance as the static resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource viewModel}" />
```

Hope this helps someone.