# Page resources in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am working on a Windows Phone application based on C# Silverlight. I am thinking if there is a way can let me keep all my pages in a res file that can help me reference to the pages?

I saw someone asked this kind of question here: [Is this XAML code possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905007/is-this-xaml-code-possible)

But the answer was too simple that I cannot understand the usage of it. So if anyone can share some idea or example that will be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to store references to pages?

Comment: What part of the page are you trying to store and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think your approach is a bit strange and it would need very good reason to do it this way.

In SO question that you reference to user declares resources that hold his ViewModels. If you are familiar with [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) then you know that it is not exactly what you are asking about and his approach is also "not the way I would do it". It is possible in silverlight to load multiple xap files that can contain views or from some [stream](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/10/09/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-60-how-to-load-a-control-straight-from-xaml.aspx). But I would strongly recommend that you just stay in main stream of app development - it will be easier for you.

If you provide some more explanation for your concrete scenario I might be more helpful.